# Pasar datos de javascript a php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando pasar algunos datos de un formulario pasándolos por ajax pero por alguna razón a la página que se envían los datos no llega nada. Este es mi código javascript:

```
        </script>
            <!-- Apertura Script -->
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#envio').click(function(){
                 var usuario = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
                 var telefono = document.getElementById("telefono").value;
                 var comentario = document.getElementById("comentario").value;
                  document.getElementById("usuario").innerHTML = usuario;
                    $("#formularioUsuario").hide(0);
                  $("#mensajeDespedida").show(800);
                  var url = "form.php";                                      
                  var parametros = {
                    "nombre" : usuario,
                    "telefono" : telefono,
                    "comentario" : comentario
    };
                  $.ajax({                        
                     type: "POST",                 
                     url: url,                    
                     data: parametros,
                     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)             
                    {

                        location.href ="http://localhost/a/form.php";          
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                    alert('Ha ocurrido un error'); 
                }         
                   });
                });
                });
                        </script>
                        <!-- Cierre script -->
```

Y este es mi código php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['telefono'])){
echo "Llegó";
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$comentario = $_POST['comentario'];

$resultado = $nombre=$_POST['nombre'] .  $telefono = $_POST['telefono'] .  $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
$json = json_encode($resultado);
echo $json;
}

else {
    echo "No ha llegado";
}
?>
```

Agrego además el HTML, este dispara un modal:

```
 <div id="formularioUsuario">
        <form id="formUser" name="formUser" method="post"  class="col-md-4 control-label">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre"> Nombre:
                <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" autofocus>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="telefono"> Telefono:
                <input type="tel" id="telefono" name="telefono" class="form-control">
            </label>
        </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="test">
            <label for="telefono"> Comentario:</label><br>
            <textarea  id="comentario" name="comentario" class="form-control" rows="4" cols="5" maxlength="100" placeholder="Agrega información adicional de lo que quieres que hablemos."></textarea> 
            </br>
            <div class="modal-body">

        </div>      
                <input type="button" id="envio" value="Enviar">        
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

El ajax no me lanza ningún error pero al carga la página "form.php" el echo disparado es "No ha llegado".

Yo no veo el error. ¿Qué podría ser?

Comment: debes usar la consola de errores (F12 si estas en CHROME) del navegador para ver el error

Comment: de casualidad el boton  #envio es un submit?

Comment: Hola. 
1. La consola no me lanza ningún error.

2. Es de tipo button.

Comment: Agregaré el HTML por si acaso.

Comment: Hay ke aprender a trabajar mas con el navegador. En el mozilla o en el chrome con el f12 abres la herramienta de desarrollador busca la pestaña Red o Network, selecciona XHR solamente y revisa que es lo que hace tu ajax

Comment: Dariel, el navegador no me dice mucho, de hecho, esta es la información que me da:

Status: 200
Type: XHR
Initiator: code.jquery...

Voy a echar un vistazo a ver qué otra cosa se puede saber.

Comment: Agrega un console.log(data) dentro del bloque de success, y ver que respuesta regresa.

Comment: Hola. Devuelve todo el html con los datos enviados. Así: 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"></head><body>
Llegó"Carlos31385554545qwfqw"</body></html></body></html>

Comment: Si comentas tu validación solo para verificar que los datos estén llegando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya entendi tu problema lo que sucede es que cuando el ajax te devuelve la respuesta tu la redireccionas comenta la linea de

```
location.href ="http://localhost/a/form.php";
```

y coloca un alert en la funcion sucsess con la variable data asi

```
alert(data);
```

asi veras la respuesta que te devuelve tu php

Comment: Hola. De hecho el href lo puse para ver si redirigiendo desde allí podía visualizar los datos capturados en el form.php, y no, ni así.  Pero he puesto algo parecido, un cosole.log y me devuelve todo el html. Curioso.

Comment: pero el ajax no funciona asi si redireccionas pierdes la informacion enviada al archivo php si el console.log te esta devolviendo el html deberias de revisar si el archivo al cual estas enviando los datos es el correcto

Comment: otra cosa que me fije en tu codigo es que tienes esta linea
$resultado = $nombre=$_POST['nombre'] .  $telefono = $_POST['telefono'] .  $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];

y despues tratas de convertirlo a json el formato esta mal tendrias que agregar esas variables a un array y despues convertirlo a json